# Why my Android app works from Eclips but fails if disconnected from PC?

Tags: galaxy

My app works fine on the Samsung Galaxy S III device (SPH-L710) when connected to Eclips running on Windows 7 but fails if the USB cable is disconnected. I picked my device through the Run Configuration box. My app accesses a production REST WCF web service to get data to populate a spinner. However, once disconnected, the spinner gets stuck at taps and it seems the whole app gets stuck.

Did I do anything wrong? How can I fix this? Thanks for any tip.

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint set. Perhaps it is making it appear stuck when it really isn't. I'm guessing that is not the problem though.

Comment: Is it a debug build? If so, it requires a connection to the debugger to start running, and will appear hung while the app waits for the debugger to connect. You need to do a non-debug (release) build to run outside the IDE.

Comment: Thanks.  I think this is the issue.  I thought if I run my app from Eclips and not debug it, the deployed app should in in release mode.  Obviously, this is not the case.  I'll try to build the release version and let you know.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Josiah and Ken, I found that the issue was caused by an embedded waitForDebugger() statement I forgot to delete.